# C# Singleton Form pattern, how to run 2 and more forms?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm trying to run multiple singleton forms at the same time, but having problem with it. 
I want to run few forms that will be the same, because they are the same object, I'm not trying to make few singleton object (singleton lose it meaning if few object created).
I have this code for singleton form:

> ```
> class SingletonForm : Form
> {
>     private static readonly SingletonForm instance = new SingletonForm();
>
>     public static SingletonForm Instance
>     {
>         get
>         {
>             return instance;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

I tried to do:

> ```
>     SingletonForm f1 = SingletonForm.Instance;
>     SingletonForm f2 = SingletonForm.Instance;
>     f1.Show();
>     Application.Run(f2);
> ```

But it only run 1 form.

How to run it so it could run 2 and more singleton forms at the same time ? and if it possible (I mean easily done)?

P.S. I was told that it possible, and that I should try it.

Comment: "multiple singleton forms" is an oxymoron.  Clearly you don't actually want a singleton here.  So don't use it.

Comment: Actually it makes sense in that you might want one instance of a specific form.

Comment: @Lloyd yes - but the OP wants to multiply instantiate a singleton, which doesn't make sense

Comment: @Charleh Yeh you're right of course.

Comment: Why do you use f1.Show() and Application.Run(f2)? Why don't you use for both forms the Show-Method?

Comment: The purpose of a singleton is to ensure you only have 1 object of that type.  Showing 2 "views" of that 1 object is a bit silly.  You need to determine why it's a singleton to begin with and either remove that or change your approach to only show 1.

Answer (score 2):

It is the **Singleton** pattern, meaning you can only get a **SINGLE** object. If you want to get N* objects, then just remove it from being a singleton and call the constructor.

If you really want, you could create some sort of hybrid static that allows you to set the max number of instances that could be returned.

```
public static int MaxInstances;
public static List<MyObject> instanceList;
public static MyObject GetInstance()
{
    //Fill the instance list up to the MaxInstances
}
```

However, managing this is going to be difficult and probably cause bugs. You might be able to pass back the index of the instance I guess, and then request instances by index also. But, again, this seems really error prone and you should just use instances like normal